# How to call an attribute of textarea nested in table cell?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website where I can upload an Excel Sheet, which will be printed out on the website in a table. Some cells of the table has textareas which can be edited. At the end of the table is a button which should save all in an array.

The table has 3 columns and many rows. Column 2 and 3 has textareas nested in table cells. Now I want to store the textarea value in an array in JS calling the Id of the current textarea. IDs for textarea are given dynamically and the array should be filled dynamically too. I want to go through all table cells and save the value of the current table cell/textarea. Table cell is no problem. But the thing with the Textareas doesn't work.

First, I went through every table row and cell, and put the text in the array.
It worked, but then I noticed that, when I edit the textarea, the updated value isn't taken. First, I had .text(), then I tried .val(), which didnt worked.
I thought the problem is that i call the .val() on "td" which is ""

PHP:

```php
echo '<td><textarea class="form-control" style="overflow:hidden; resize:none; min-height:62px;" onkeyup="auto_grow(this)" cols="10" id="ta'.$taID.'" type=text style="border:none">' . ( ! empty( $r[ 1 ] ) ? $r[ 1 ] : '&nbsp;') . '</textarea></td>';
$taID++;
```

JS:

```
var tableData = new Array(5);
$('#tblAusgabe tr').each(function(row, tr){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
         var inputString = $(tr).find('td:eq('+i+')').text();
         if(i==0){
             tableData[arrIndex][mitarbeiterCount][i] = 
             inputString.substr(2,inputString.length-3);
         }
         else if(i==1){
             tableData[arrIndex][mitarbeiterCount][i] = inputString;
         }
         else{
             var taid=$(tr).find('td:eq('+i+')').attr('id'); // not working
             console.log("1."+$(tr).find('td:eq('+i+')').attr('id')); //test
             console.log("2."+taid);                                  //test
             tableData[arrIndex][mitarbeiterCount][i] = $(this).val();
         }

     }
}
```

I want something like

```
var id = $(thisElement).attr('id');
array[index]= $(id).val();
```

But I don't know how to call the ID of textarea. Or is there any easier way to do it ?

Hope, you understand the problem and can help me.
Sorry for no perfect English, I'm German and its my first question :)

Comment: Can you post a sample structure of the output? And Sample HTML table

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what does your result array looks like @Eddy_SPL

Comment: My table has 5 header, so the first index of the 3d array is the header, the second is the row and the third is the column

Comment: I want to go through every table cell and do something with the cell value at runtime. Isnt there a possibility to get the ID of my current textarea at runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in another way. I did it with a counter and every time a textarea was gone through the counter counted 1 up.

```
tableData[arrIndex][mitarbeiterCount][i]=document.getElementById("ta"+count).value;
count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to loop thru each `tr`. `find` all `textarea`s and `reduce` to an object using the id as the property name and value.

```js
var result = $('#tblAusgabe tr').map(function(i, o) {
  return $(o).find('textarea').get().reduce(function(c, v) {
    c[v.id] = v.value;
    return c;
  }, {});
}).get();


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblAusgabe">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td><textarea id="ta01a">apple</textarea></td><td><textarea id="ta01b">orange</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td><textarea id="ta02a">red</textarea></td><td><textarea id="ta02b">blue</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td><textarea id="ta03a">php</textarea></td><td><textarea id="ta03b">javascript</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```